# SOAPAction not recognized if sent from OS X or iOS

Tags: macos, soap, ios

I'm trying to access a SOAP webservice from iOS.

But I only get this response:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<soap:Fault>
<faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>Den spesifiserte SOAPAction ble ikke gjenkjent.</faultstring>
<detail/>
</soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The fault string says: *The specified SOAPAction was not recognized.* (Translated from Norwegian.)

If I send the SOAP request from a Windows box I get the correct response.

I also tried to use curl on my Mac to send the request but got the same error response as I got when I sent from iOS.

I used Wireshark to check the SOAP requests on the machine that runs the server. (It's a webservice built into an application so I don't have any control over it.)

The request that was accepted and sent from the windows box, and the request that was not accepted and sent from OS X with curl has the exact same XML and http-headers.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Can you post the HTTP header SOAPAction for the working & non-working requests, it sounds like the non-working request is either missing the SOAPAction header altogether, or has a different value.

Comment: Thats the problem thou.. The SOAPAction and all other headers are exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

have you checked line breaks and character set encoding?
XML is very special about this, set the character set of your XML to UTF-8 or something more universal, and check that the line breaks are compatible, I'll put the line breaks as if they where C strings, the line breaks on windows are \r\n as in mac i believe are only \n